# Open browser on top of everything

Tags: java, swing, browser, jframe, window

I have a small code, which is used to open the standard browser of the users PC on a specific URL.

Here is the code:

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
            {
            try {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://www.example.com/"));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Mpame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Mpame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            }
```

Only problem is that my application which consists of a Jframe window is always on top, because it has to. But then whenever I click on the button to open the browser, the application is overlapping the browser. I was then wondering whether there is a method to have the browser open on top, like whenever you set the Jframe property "alway on top". But instead it is on the browser, so that the browser would open on top of the application.

Comment: LOL! It always amuses me when programmers get into a fight with another app. that wants to be always in top. This is even funnier given you want both your frame ***and the browser*** to be always on top. You can't have your pie, and eat it too! ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I appreciate the humor I guess, it probably isn't possible then. It just seemed as if there could be a possibility, considering it is possible to open one window on top of another, then I just thought that was possible for the browser as well.